# Macro to select last data point in line chart and add a data label

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line chart with 60 different data series in Excel that updates once a week. In this chart, I would like to program a macro that selects the most recent data points in the line charts and adds a data label in the format 100.00 (number with two decimal places).

I am now using the code below to delete all data labels:

```
Sub Delete_labels()

ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowNone

End Sub
```

To add data labels, I would like to use a code as well. I have been experimenting with the code below:

```
Sub Add_last_label()

ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabel, , , , True, False, False, False, False

End Sub
```

However, this code adds data labels to each data point, creating a huge mess. The string ", , , , True, False, False, False, False" must be adapted to only add the last data label in the chart, but I am unsure how.

Does anyone have an idea how to data labels to the last point in each series in the format 100.00 (with two decimal points)?

Comment: Take a look at this [related question on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/920162/hide-data-label-containing-series-name-if-value-is-zero/920246#920246).  Hopefully it gives you an idea of how to iterate through the data points and add/modify a data label.  Once you have some code together, post it here with a specific question about what is not working.  Right now, you've posted a specification, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The code below works:

```
Sub Update_labels()

ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowNone

Dim iSrs As Long
Dim iPts As Long
For iSrs = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(iSrs)
iPts = .Points.Count
With .Points(iPts)
.ApplyDataLabels
' .DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = -1
' .DataLabel.ShowLegendKey = -1

.DataLabel.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

End With
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Uncomment ShowSeriesName and ShowLegendKey to also show those items.